# Why does this site fall under "culture/recreation"?

Tags: discussion

If you look at the StackExchange footer - shown at the bottom of all the network sites - you will see that English Language & Usage is categorised under "Culture/Recreation". I'm not sure if it is just me, but it doesn't seem right. English isn't purely cultural, nor is it exactly recreational. Sure, people take enjoyment from writing novels and such, but the writing itself - and the grammar rules and styles - is best described as an art.

When you look under the Culture/Recreation category you will see communities such as Skeptics, Christianity and Bicycles. At the top there's English Language & Usage and it looks rather out of place.

I think ELU would fit nicely with Academia, which is filed under "Life/Arts".

Comment: It seems to fit in well with the other cultural sites, in my opinion. "Recreation" if anything seems the odd one out to me. But does any of this matter at all?

Comment: To be honest, most of the questions and answers don't seem terribly academic, either.  Maybe since there are so many language sites now, they could make a new language category?

Comment: @snailboat I think that makes a lot more sense! Maybe you should raise that on Meta.SE.